# JavaScript Regx to remove certain string if a pattern is found

Tags: regex

Lets say i have
input string as

```
<div id="infoLangIcon"></div>ARA, DAN, ENGLISHinGERMAN, FRA<div id="infoPipe"></div><div id="infoRating0"></div><div id="infoPipe"></div><div id="infoMonoIcon"></div>
```

so i want to check if inforating is 0 and then remove the div and previous div also. The output is

```
<div id="infoLangIcon"></div>ARA, DAN, ENGLISHinGERMAN, FRA</div><div id="infoPipe"></div><div id="infoMonoIcon"></div
```

Comment: I can't understand any part of this. What is your question?

Comment: I have one variable which stores some div tags and in that variable i need to search for specific string and if that string is found i need to remove that string plus previous string also.

Comment: I posted that before you had finished editing the question apparently. When I initially looked at this post there was no html in it at all. Just random strings.

Comment: You could use a regular expression to do what you've asked here, but as the html get slightly more complex the regex will get much more complex very quickly. For manipulating html elements you should stick with a technology that is designed to manipulate html such as the DOM or XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not your best option here. It is not reliable when it comes to HTML.

I suggest you use DOM functions to do this (I gave you a Javascript example, you have not provided a language to be used). If I understood correctly, if there is an element with the ID of `infoRating0`, you want to remove it and its previous sibling. This little snippet should do that:

```
if (document.getElementById('infoRating0')) {
    var rating0=document.getElementById('infoRating0'),
         rParent=rating0.parentNode;
    rParent.removeChild(rating0.previousSibling);
    rParent.removeChild(rating0);    
}
```

Also, your HTML is invalid. **You can only use an ID once** in your HTML. You have two divs with the same ID (`infoPipe`) which you should REALLY fix. Use classes instead.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Gnw5/)

Comment: This is true, but I didn't give this as the answer since I wasn't sure if he was using user input or not. If he is then there are a few considerations around sanitization to be made. Figured the only reason someone would want to use a regex on html would be because they don't trust it enough to put it into a page (in order to use the DOM).

Comment: @wewals The details he provided are not enough to give a good, detailed answer. That's why I came up with a basic example. Regex is certainly not the way to go here.